# What`s the reason that height:auto sometimes it`s 0

Tags: css, image, height, responsive

```css
#banner {
background: url(http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/lazar1-1920.jpg) no-repeat center center/contain;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/lazar1-1920.jpg" alt="">
```

I have running always into the problem with the responsive images,and i did not find an answer to clarify the problem.

The problem is with image

```
image {
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

when i add a simple image and style it, it works. when i start a project more complex with a lot of divs and I set the same properties doesn't work anymore. What's the purest explanation for this.

Comment: I don't know if it applies to your situation, but `height:auto` gives a height of 0 to containers of floated elements. Perhaps this is why you only see it sometimes. The solution is to add `overflow:auto;` to the parent container. However some believe even this is overkill, and that `overflow-y:auto; is sufficient.

Comment: I was playing with code pen and figured out a thing,when the image is in HTML it works,when il have a div with a class and add a background image to that class doesn`t work anymore but still don`t know why

Comment: Can you link the codepen?

Comment: i added 2 code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you add the `<img>` to the html directly, the browser sets the height of the element to the height of the image you provided (unless otherwise specified). When you add the image as a background of a `<div>` and set the height to auto, it tries to size the div to the height of the content. However, in this case, there is no content -- only a background that will be the background once the div has some height. An empty div has no height. Therefore, if you want the image to be the background of the `<div>`, it must either contain some content, or have its height set manually.